# Should I have asked this Space Telescope question here instead?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

I posted [Will the James Webb Space Telescope be able to see the Spitzer Space Telescope (assuming…)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41172/12102) in Space Exploration SE because the observer and observed are both spacecraft, but now I'm wondering if this should have been posted here instead.

Answering this question requires some understanding of the telescope's infrared camera's sensitivity and thermal infrared brightness of objects in orbit around the Sun, and that's the kind of thing that astronomers do.

1. Should I have asked this Space Telescope question here instead?
2. If so, should I now just delete it there and post it here? Or [as discussed here](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/would-this-us-supreme-court-question-be-on-topic-here-and-likely-to-receive-an-a#comment11469_4264) should I wait for feedback here, then flag it there to close with affirmative answers here indicating that the question is more likely to be answered here?

It would be answerable here if Spitzer were treated as a near Earth asteroid of approximately the same size, with the caveat that the emissivity will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is about astronomical operation of space telescopes, I think it would be on topic here, but it's also on topic on Space Exploration. If you would like it migrated here nonetheless, flag the question and I can migrate it.

Comment: I'll wait a little bit longer to see if someone expresses some likelihood that it would receive an answer here, thanks!